# Is it possible to translate a group of vertices that haven't been yet attached to a model? (scripting)

Tags: scripting, transforms

Suppose that I have **n** vectors with vertices values that represent circles of various sizes and some are deformed, the only thing that they have in common is that they all have their center in (0,0,0). **Now my question is: Can I translate those circles on the Z axis to create a tube by specifying their new center? Can I also rotate them?**

PS: before you ask, I want to know if I can somehow use a bpy function to attain this, I am aware that I can painfully calculate the translated vertices of all those circles myself.
(I am looking for something like translatedCircleVerts = bpy.ops.transform.translate(newCenter,circleVerts) )

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.translate plus an example at the begining of the page.

Comment: @lemon I haven't worked yet with bmesh, but will it work directly with arrays of vertices?

Comment: Yes: last argument of this bmesh.ops.